# Combine similar sort functions

Tags: javascript, function, sorting

I am still a newbie in javascript and in the process of creating a todo-list (exercise). Now my list should be sortable, this i could also solve with one function each. Since there are now three (almost) identical functions, I wonder if there is a way to solve this with only one function?

My first function sorts alphabetically by string:

```
function sortTitle(array) {
  
  return array.sort((a,b) => {

    const titleA = a.title.toUpperCase();
    const titleB = b.title.toUpperCase();

    let comparison = 0;
    if (titleA > titleB) {
      comparison = 1;
    } else if (titleA < titleB) {
      comparison = -1;
    }
    return comparison;
  })
}

titleSort.addEventListener("click", () => {
    sortTitle(todos);
    cleanTodo();
    showTodos();
});
```

the other functions sort date and priority by number.

```
function sortDate(array) {
  
  return array.sort((a,b) => {
  
    let comparison = 0;
    if (a.duedate > b.duedate) {
      comparison = 1;
    } else if (a.duedate < b.duedate) {
      comparison = -1;
    }
    return comparison;
  })
}

dateSort.addEventListener("click", () => {
    sortDate(todos);
    cleanTodo();
    showTodos();
  }
);



function sortPrio(array) {
  return array.sort((a,b) => {

        let comparison = 0;
        if (a.prio > b.prio) {
            comparison = 1;
        } else if (a.prio < b.prio) {
            comparison = -1;
        }
        return comparison;
    })
}

prioSort.addEventListener("click", () => {

    sortPrio(todos);
    cleanTodo();
    showTodos();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that accepts an array and a "key" function and sorts by that key. The key function is supposed to convert a complex array element into a sortable scalar value.

The sort function works this way:

- iterate over the array, apply the key func to each element and create a list of pairs `[key value, element]`
- sort this list by the key value
- map over the sorted list and get rid of the key value

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform for more details about this technique.

Example:

```js
let sortBy = (ary, keyFn) => ary
    .map(item => [keyFn(item), item])
    .sort((a, b) => (a[0] > b[0]) - (a[0] < b[0]))
    .map(pair => pair[1])

//

a = [
    {title: 'a', date: 9},
    {title: 'z', date: 8},
    {title: 'b', date: 7},
    {title: 'w', date: 6},
    {title: 'c', date: 5},
    {title: 'x', date: 4},
    {title: 'd', date: 3},
]

console.log(sortBy(a, item => item.title.toUpperCase()))
console.log(sortBy(a, item => item.date))
```